# is there a pecil and paper type rpg that you can play by yourself?

Tags: game-recommendation

I am looking for an old style rpg that I can play by myself. is there such a thing? I was kinda thinking the munchkin series was like that

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a tactical dungeon crawl, the DMG of 4e specifies how to do so.

If you are looking for more story, look to [Mythic Game Master Emulator](http://www.mythic.wordpr.com/page14/page9/page9.html). It is designed to be playable solo.

But ultimately, if you are looking for just the tactics, I would suggest looking into a solo playthrough of one of the D&D board games, e.g. [Castle Ravenloft](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/board-games/castle-ravenloft-board-game)